# javafx remove specific node from VBox

Tags: javafx

i have the following method:

```
CreateStrip createStrip = new CreateStrip(input);
depBox.getChildren().add(createStrip.getStripGrid());
```

depBox is a VBox and .getStripGrid() return a GridPane.
CreateStrip has this method too:

```
public String getNameStrip() { return input.getNameStrip();}
```

during the life of the program depBox get many GridPane, each one with a different NameStrip.
sometimes i have the necessity to remove a specific GridPane from depBox that match with .getNameStrip().
i have tried:

```
    for (Node node: depBox.getChildren()) {

//TODO REMOVE GRIDPANE CONTAIN THE NAME THAT MATCH WITH THE MESSAGE RECEIVED..
            }
```

but i don't know how to set the matching control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1:

Attach data to the `GridPane` that allows you to identify the one to remove.

You could do this by using [`Node.setUserData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) or by using the [`properties` `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--) (which I'll do in the following code snippets).

**Creating the `GridPane`**

```
GridPane gp = createStrip.getStripGrid();
gp.getProperties().put(NAME_KEY, createStrip);
depBox.getChildren().add(gp);
```

```
// use object not equal to any other object as key (i.e. equals uses reference equality)
static final Object NAME_KEY = new Object();
```

#### Step 2:

Use the information to remove the appropriate `GridPane`. `searchName` is the `String` that identifies the `GridPane` you want to remove (to check for equality with `getNameStrip()`):

```
depBox.getChildren().removeIf(c -> {
     CreateStrip strip = (CreateStrip) c.getProperties().get(NAME_KEY);
     return strip != null && searchName.equals(strip.getNameStrip());
});
```

Depending on your `CreateStrip` class it may not be necessary to add a instance of it as property. It may not even be the right thing to do, if it's a factory, but I think you get the idea nontheless.

### Alternative

You can also assign a value to the `id` property of the `Node` and use those to identify the correct node using `Node.lookup`. However those need to be unique and be a valid css id, but you could use a `Map` to map from message to `id`.

Comment: how can i define my NAME_KEY as  static final Object NAME_KEY = new Object(); ? i receive a String so the object in my case should be static final Object "String" = new Object()...but i can't do that.

Comment: one more thing, searchName.equals what does it mean?

Comment: @Daniele_r81: `NAME_KEY` is the key for the `properties` map of the `GridPane`s. `searchName` is just a placeholder for the `String` to search. What `equals` means? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: really sorry but i didn't get it before...ill try as soon as possible and ill give you my feedback. thanks.

Comment: yes it work...thanks a lot. May i use this method even for update some filed inside the gridPane?

Comment: ok done...i use the same concept fabian suggest me. thanks again

Comment: @Daniele_r81 Of course you can use `depBox.getChildren().stream().filter(predicate).findFirst()` with the same `Predicate` used with `removeIf` in my answer. We're just attaching information to the `Node` that can be used to identify it here...